# FCM is not working when app is closed

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created an app with FCM push notifications. I have done that by using samples from FCM manuals and git repositories. All is fine when app is in foreground or background but when I killed the app, I cannot receive push notifications. The service is not running. Could anyone tell me how do telegram, whatsapp or skype do that when the app is closed?

Comment: which device you testing on?

Comment: I am testin on Meizu m5. Tried with telegram, all is fine when app is closed.

Comment: http://forum.flymeos.com/thread-22736-1-1.html read this thread.Your app may be disabled in the security app, which disables your app to run in background. Enable autorun for your app

Comment: http://forum.flymeos.com/thread-5745-1-1.html

Answer (score 1):

**There are two types of messages in FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging):**

1. **Display Messages:** These messages trigger the onMessageReceived()
   callback only when your app is in foreground.
2. **Data Messages:** Theses messages trigger the onMessageReceived()
       callback even if your app is in foreground/background/killed

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: I can get push notifications on Alcatel and ZTE but with Meizu I got nothing.

Comment: Are you got notification when app opened for Meizu ?

Comment: I use data message and I get push notification when the app is in foreground or background on Meizu but when app is closed I couldn't get anything. When I test my app on ZTE or Alcatel I can get the push notification when app is closed.

Comment: @ViramP where did you get the info, that app will receive a message if it is killed? From what I got, it wont.